# Is there any way to check that a type is a type of enumeration?

Tags: c#, enumeration, typechecking

Somebody gives me a type t.

I'd like to know if that type is an enumeration or not.

```
public bool IsEnumeration(Type t)
{
    // Mystery Code.
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void IsEnumerationChecker()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(IsEnumeration(typeof(Color)));
    Assert.IsFalse(IsEnumeration(typeof(float)));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also check by using property [`IsEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx)  on `Type`:

```
Type t = typeof(DayOfWeek);
bool isEnum = t.IsEnum;
```

Comment: @user .NET is huge, nobody knows every method and property.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways you can achieve this:

```
return typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t != typeof(Enum);
```

or

```
return typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsValueType;
```

or (now that I've seen [it exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) while checking `IsValueType`)

```
return t.IsEnum;
```

Obviously the latter is the best approach, but the first two will give you hints about how to handle similar situations.